# Django 1.10 + Django Restless 0.0.10 e Request vazio

Tags: django, python-2.7

Estou utilizando django restless views para construir algumas interfaces REST e em todos os posts o request.POST e o request.params estão em branco.

Caso eu execute:

```
print request
print request.POST
```

Tenho o seguinte retorno:

```
<WSGIRequest: POST '/ambiente/alo/cadastrosplash/448/'>
<QueryDict: {}>
```

Segue o cabeçalho dos método que herda de restless.views.Endpoint:

```
from restless.views import Endpoint
class CadastroSplash(Endpoint):
    def post(self, request, idCampanha, **kwargs):
```

No url.py, a configuração está desta maneira:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import ensure_csrf_cookie
from meuprojeto.meupacote.views import CadastroSplash

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^cadastrosplash/(?P<idCampanha>\d{1,8})/$$',
         ensure_csrf_cookie(CadastroSplash.as_view())),
]
```

Desta maneira o método "post" é executado corretamente, o valor do parâmetro `idCampanha` vem preenchido, porém com os campos do request vazios.

Caso eu crie um view method o request vem corretamente preenchido, mas é algo que eu não gostaria de fazer pelo bem da padronização dos métodos.

Algumas informações adicionais: estou utilizando django com apache2 e módulo WSGI. 
O formulário é um multipart/form-data para upload de arquivos.
Existe esta mesma aplicação rodando com django 1.5 e djangorestless 0.0.9 no mesmo servidor em um virtualenv separado, este método funciona corretamente e recebe todos os parâmetros.

Agradeço a todos a atenção

Answer (score 0):

Entrei em contato com o desenvolvedor do djangorestless no github.

O método `dispatch` da classe `restless.views.Endpoint` possui na primeira linha:

```
request.content_type = request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE', 'text/plain')
```

Este código quando é executado faz com que um formulário multipart/form-data seja limpo no django 1.10.

Desenvolvedor já informou que irá corrigir o problema.